# WebGL : From World to Screen Coordinates

Tags: math, screen, webgl

i have read all the posts about it, but cant get it done.
I have a 3d scene in webgl and need to know the 2d on the canvas for a 3d point.

I have this matrixes:

```
Perspective    = M4x4.makePerspective( fovy, aspect, znear, zfar );
CameraView     = M4x4.makeLookAt ( eye,  center, up );  
ViewPerspectiv = M4x4.mul(  Perspective , CameraView );
```

And the model has:

```
this.ModelMatrix  = M4x4.I;  
this.ModelMatrix  = M4x4.makeTranslate3( this.pos_x, this.pos_y, this.pos_z );
```

I have tryed all the posts - it always uses: view and Perspective and point .. and sometimes a transpose...

can someone use my varaiable names and just post me the lines ?? PLS !!
here is what i tryed .. but it did not work:

```
var point = get2dPoint( point,  this.ModelMatrix,  ViewPerspectiv ,  canvas.clientWidth,  canvas.clientHeight ) ;
...
function get2dPointV2( point3D,  viewMatrix,  projectionMatrix,  width,  height) 
{ 
   var tmp1 = multiMat4ByVec3( viewMatrix ,  point3D );
   var clip = multiMat4ByVec3( projectionMatrix ,  tmp1 );

   var ndcSpace = new Array ( clip[0] / clip[3]   ,   clip[1] / clip[3]   , clip[2] / clip[3]  ); 

   ndcSpace[0] = ((ndcSpace[0] + 1.0) / 2.0) * width ;
   ndcSpace[1] = ((ndcSpace[1] + 1.0) / 2.0) * height ;

   return ndcSpace;
```

}

This is killing me for 12hours now..

Thanx to anybody who trys to help.

cu

### uwi

i found out thet the basic approche was fine but the matrix i used needed to be transposed , that was all that was missing !
thanx anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence sounds like you want to project 3D -> 2D. Thats what the Perspective-Matrix does.

Your code is trying to invert the Perspective-Matrix, projecting from 2D -> 3D. This is used e.g. when trying to find out where you clicked with your mouse.

What are you trying to do? If you actually want to project 2D -> 3D i might find the time to explain/post some code tomorrow.